# Как создать объект типа T

Tags: java, generics

У меня есть метод с параметром

```
<T> void testMethod(Consumer<T> arg) {
  T t = ???;
  arg.accept(t);
}
```

Как создать объект типа `T` при условии что `T` имеет конструктор по умолчанию?

Вот код, который я испытывал

```
public class MethodConsumer {
  private <T> void test(T t) {  // Consumer<T>
    System.out.println("test()"+t);
  };

  <T> void testMethod(Consumer<T> arg) {
    T t = null;
    arg.accept(t);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    MethodConsumer test = new MethodConsumer();
    test.testMethod((t) -> test.test(t));
  }

}
```

Comment: Через рефлексию можно попробовать. Но это не точно.

Comment: Просто через `T` - никак, ибо type erasure. Нужен объект типа `Class` (лучше `Class<T>`)

Comment: Можно использовать фабричный метод

Comment: @Regent Но где мне взять такой объект?

Comment: @rjhdby Мне нужно просто вызвать метод, который создает T и передает его в лямбду, как я могу использоавть фабрику?

Comment: @RomanC задача описана крайне скупо. Если объекты класса Т реализуют один интерфейс, то можно в нем определить необходимость метода `public static create(){return new MyClass()}` и использовать приватный конструктор.

Comment: @rjhdby В данном примере объекты класса T никакие интерфейсы не реализуют, но можно прикрутить другой класс, который это делает с помощью `<T extends MyClass>`. И тогда параметр `t` нужно кастить к указанному типу или же использовать ссылку на метод. Последнее я хотел спросить в новом вопросе, почему каст нельзя обойти в первом случае и можно обойти во втором.

Comment: @rjhdby Кажется понял последнее связано с тем, что у ссылочного метода тип параметра указан явно, а в лямбде тип параметра не указан.

Comment: Непонятно экземпляр чего вы хотите создать. Зачем вам вообще generic метод testMethod, если в нем вы пытаетесь создать экземпляр конкретного класса?

Comment: Почему бы просто не добавить в сигнатуру второй аргумент - `Supplier<T>`, который и будет нужным конструктором?

Comment: @MikhailBaksheev Создать надо объект, который можно присвоить переменной `t`. Генерик метод нужен для того, чтобы можно было создать объект, который получает  параметр `T`. О конкретном классе я упомянул в предыдущем коменте, но в вопросе этого нет.

Comment: @iksuy если я добавлю второй параметр `Supplier<T>` то тогда я не могу использовать лямбду.

Comment: Какой ожидается результат от исполнения этого кода? Какой объект придет в `test`?

Comment: @RomanC, как это не сможете? `test.testMethod(MethodConsumer::new, (t) -> test.test(t))`;

Comment: @iksuy ок, так оно работает, только почему надо передавать еще один функциональный аргумент?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще то, то что вы пытаетесь сделать запрещено, [читайте туториал](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createObjects)

> You cannot create an instance of a type parameter.

Оно и понятно, шаблон не живет сам по себе, он живет только с конкретным типом.

В вашем случае рабочий код может выглядеть приблизительно так:

```
 <T> void testMethod(Consumer<T> arg, Class<T> clazz) {
    T t = clazz.newInstance(); //надо ловить эксепшн
    arg.accept(t);
  }
```

Обратите внимание, что во втором параметре мы указываем тип `T`

А вызов его типа, так:

```
String s="blabla";
test.testMethod(arg, s.class);
```

Comment: Я хочу передать лямбду в качестве аргумента в `testMethod()`. Лямбда должна иметь один аргумент.

Comment: Какая разница лямбда не лямбда? Лямбда всего лишь синтаксический сахар, зашлите в лямбду 2 параметра...

Comment: Как это сделать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27872387/can-a-java-lambda-have-more-than-1-parameter

Comment: @RomanC test.testMethod(arg, s.class); arg - это и есть ваша лямбда, и ей не нужен второй параметр. clazz - это аргумент не лямбды, а метода  testMethod. В вашем случае test.testMethod((t) -> test.test(t), s.class);

Comment: @MikhailBaksheev Вот, я как раз этого понять не могу, зачем ему этот аргумент.

Comment: @Barmaley Мне не подходит второй аргумент, надо тип вытащить из первого. Возможно ли такое `(Class<T>)arg.getClass()`?

Answer (score 2):

```
   <T> void testMethod(Consumer<T> arg) {
      T t = ???;
      arg.accept(t);
    }
```

В этом случае попытка создать новый экземпляр класса противоречит самой идее шаблонов.

Шаблоны нужны для того, чтобы отвязать алгоритм работы с данными от конкретной реализации данных. Например LinkdList'у без разницы что у него внутри, алгоритм для всех типов данных один и тот же. Шаблон работает с **любым** типом данных, но нельзя создать объект **любого** типа, потому что непонятно что создавать.

Если вам нужно работать с каким-то конкретным типом данных, то его и используйте.

```
public class MethodConsumer {
  class MyClass{
  }
  private <T> void test(T t) {  // Consumer<T>
    System.out.println("test()"+t);
  };

  void testMethod(Consumer<MyClass> arg) {
    MyClass t = new MyClass();
    arg.accept(t);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    MethodConsumer test = new MethodConsumer();
    test.testMethod((t) -> test.test(t));
  }
}
```

Comment: я хотел сделать как-то чтобы по лямбде можно было вывести тип консюмера и следовательно создать объект этого типа не меняя обобщенность типа. Я пытался также специализировать метод вызываемый лябдой `test()`, но это не дало результатов.