# Конкретный пример использования функциональных интерфейсов из коробки

Tags: java, интерфейс, java-8, функциональное-программирование

Моя вина. Мы не прошли, когда задавал вопрс, Stream-ы. Теперь я понял для чего. Вопрос удалять не буду((

Очень скудно по ним инфы. В 99% что они делают и как работают, и нигде ЗАЧЕМ они нужны.Помогите понять, пожалуйста. Дайте пример, конкретный

Predicate - проверяет некое условие.
Для чего используется - тут я понял, например для фильтрации. Привильно ли понимаю, что в Stream Api, например я могу отфильтровать клиентов при помощи Predicate всех, у кого день рождения в декабре, чтобы их поздравить.

Consumer - принимает один параметр и ничего не возвращает.
Для чего используется - понятия не имею Зачем?

Supplier - тут полный ноль, что и куда он там что-то поставляет

Function тоже самое. Ну зачем мне переделывать один элемент в другой? Если мне понадобится, почему я не могу написать, например такую конструкцию (Integer)int

Comment: подскажите, пожалуйста, а вы в ооп уже освоились? не думаю, что переходить к функциональной парадигме без ооп - хорошая идея. в целом для начала вам нужно разобраться с тем, что есть лямбда - выражение. если вы понимаете, что такое анонимный класс и как его использовть, то и с лямбдами вопрос "зачем" не возникнет. а если не понимаете, то добро пожаловать в изучении ооп

Comment: Где читал, что читал - ничего не понятно, проблему не создавал. Вот тебе [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/865174/204920) по твоей теме как задавать вопрос и описывать проблему в коде.

Comment: Функциональные интерфейсы - может быть способом сказать, что функция принимает на вход другую функцию, чтобы внутри ее можно было вызвать (если указать как параметр функциональный интерфейс). Необязательно функцию, можно лямбду или любой объект, реализующий соответствующий функциональный интерфейс. Зачем в принципе в функции передавать функции - почитайте про функции высшего порядка.

Comment: Типичный пример использования функциональных интерфейсов - объект-компаратор (Comparator), который умеет сравнивать два объекта какого-то класса. Компаратор, например, можно передать в метод сортировки списка, чтобы отсортировать объекты. Разные виды функциональных интерфейсов - это просто попытка описать всевозможные функции, их параметры и возвращаемые значения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно открыть и прочитать ,документацию интерфейса [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html),чтобы найти там массу примеров применения указанных функциональных интерфейсов

- `Predicate` используется не только в промежуточной операции `Stream::filter`, но и в терминальных операциях: `Stream::allMatch`, `Stream::anyMatch`, `Stream::noneMatch`
- `Consumer` прекрасно используется в терминальных операциях `Stream::forEach` / `Stream::forEachOrdered`, а также в промежуточной операции `Stream::peek`, которую следует использовать для отладки и вывода промежуточных значений стрима.  Наиболее популярный пример -- ссылка на метод `System.out::println`
- `Supplier` используется в `Stream::generate` и перегруженном методе `Stream::collect`, где создается кастомный коллектор, а также массе коллекторов типа `Collectors.groupingBy`, `Collectors.toMap/toConcurrentMap`, `Collectors.toCollection`, чтобы создавать объекты-"приемники" данных стрима -- различные конкретные реализации мап и коллекций
- Интерфейс `Function` и его разновидности используются для преобразования объектов в другой тип: в `Stream::map / flatMap`, `Collectors.groupingBy/toMap/toConcurrentMap` для преобразования элемента стрима в некий ключ или значение, в методах `Comparator.comparing/ thenComparing` для сравнения по полю/полям объекта, и т.д.